# Mixing enumerate and tabbing, what's wrong here?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, enumerate, tabbing

So I can't seem to figure out what's wrong with my LaTeX file. Do you guys see anything obvious?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\newcommand{\df}[1]{\textbf{#1}}

\begin{document}
\section{Midterm 1}
    \subsection{Definitions}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \begin{tabbing}
            \item \df{Determinism} \= - \= blabhablabhabhalbha
            \item \df{Parsimony} \> - \> alalalalalalala
            \end{tabbing}
        \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot nest the `tabbing` environment inside an `enumerate` in this way. Perhaps this is what you're after - alignment *after* the `-`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\newcommand{\df}[1]{\textbf{#1}}

\begin{document}
\section{Midterm 1}
\subsection{Definitions}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item \df{Determinism} - blabhablabhabhalbha
  \item \leavevmode\rlap{\df{Parsimony}}\phantom{\df{Determinism}} - alalalalalalala
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

`\leavevmode` initializes the `\item`, while `\rlap` causes a `r`ight over`lap` (zero-width, left-aligned box) of the `\phantom` (non-existent) content.

---

This can be automated to some extent using the following setup:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\newcommand{\df}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\newlength{\maxitemwidth}
\newcommand{\maxitem}[1]{\settowidth{\maxitemwidth}{#1}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Item}[1]{%
  \item #1%
  \sbox\@tempboxa{#1}%
  \ifdim\maxitemwidth>\z@\hspace*{\dimexpr\maxitemwidth-\wd\@tempboxa}\fi%
}
\begin{document}
\section{Midterm 1}
\subsection{Definitions}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item \df{Determinism} - blabhablabhabhalbha
  \item \df{Parsimony} - alalalalalalala
\end{enumerate}
Some text.
\maxitem{\df{Determinism}}\showthe\maxitemwidth
\begin{enumerate}
  \Item{\df{Determinism}} - blabhablabhabhalbha
  \Item{\df{Parsimony}} - alalalalalalala
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

You set the maximum-width item using `\maxwidth` and then use `\Item{<item>}` in the `enumerate` list. *All* subsequent lists will then be typeset with this in mind. There are other ways of doing this, but not knowing the exact usage makes this sufficient, I guess.

Comment: Holy crap I never would have gotten that on my own. What a solution! Thumbs up for you good sir.

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to make a function that does this for each word, takes in two arguments, the word to type, and the word to phantom?

Comment: @Dan: I've added some detail to this extent which is a little easier than using two arguments. It's not optimal, but it should suffice in your instance. As I mention, there should be other ways of doing this, but without knowing more about your usage its hard to make things work efficiently. Give some feedback if you need more.

Answer (score 6):

if you want also possible linebreaks in the definition

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{tabularx,lipsum}
\newcolumntype{S}{@{\stepcounter{Definition}\theDefinition.~} >{\bfseries}l @{~--~}X@{}}
\newcounter{Definition}[subsection]

\begin{document}
\section{Midterm 1}
\subsection{Definitions}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{S}
Determinism & blabhablabhabhalbha \\
Parsimony   & \lipsum[4]
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]